# Memory usage does not change in my program

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection

Given following codes which test the memory usage of a Java program:

```
List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
for (int i = 0; i <= 10000000; i++) {
  list.add(new Person("Jim", "Knopf"));
}
// Get the Java runtime
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
// Run the garbage collector
runtime.gc();
// Calculate the used memory
long memory = runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory();
System.out.println("Used memory is bytes: " + memory);
```

The output is always `286046`, no matter how I change the value of `i`. But large `i` means large memory usage, right? Any explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The output is always 286046, no matter how I change the value of i. But large i means large memory usage, right? Any explanation?

When you `gc()` the `list` is has fallen out of scope (i.e. it is not used again) and is not retained.  Try placing it in a `static` as this cannot be discarded.

Note: you will get more accurate memory accounting if you use `-XX:-UseTLAB` as this disables concurrent memory allocation makes accounting simpler.

Answer (score 1):

From the javadoc

> Returns the amount of free memory in the Java Virtual Machine. Calling
>   the gc method may result in increasing the value returned by
>   freeMemory.

My guess is that since the memory is allocated using large chunck, it always return the same because you stay on low memory usage. Try doing an higher test and don't forget to call the Garbage collector `System.gc();` to make your test more revelant.

Check this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/runtime_freememory.htm

I would also try setting the minimum memory `-Xms` very low so you have more chance to overflow the minimum and force the JVM to allocate more and reduce the `freememory`